# Hide the Stack Exchange sidebar

Tags: support, script-request, style

I would like to gain some screen estate when viewing Stack Exchange sites. The sidebar seldom shows information I need.

- I know most help content displayed when composing questions.
- Most related answers are found by the same search that already brought me to the question I am currently viewing, so I already have them open in other browser tabs anyways.
- Hot Network Questions always distracts me to [scifi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com).

I know there is a [userstyle](https://userstyles.org/) to [hide the *Hot Network Questions*](https://userstyles.org/styles/111692/stackexchange-remove-hot-network-questions-widget) and one that [completely removes the sidebar](https://userstyles.org/styles/111859/hide-the-sidebar-on-unix-stackexchange-com) leaving an ugly hole where it once was. Is it possible to hide it and have the question, list, or whatever content takes the main part of the page expand to claim its place?

Answer (score 9):

Okay, the following [Stylish](https://stackapps.com/tags/stylish/info) style should be a good start.

You can also [see / **install it at *userstyles.org***](https://userstyles.org/styles/120216/stack-exchange-expand-away-sidebar).

```css
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document
    domain("askubuntu.com"), domain("mathoverflow.net"), domain("serverfault.com"), domain("stackapps.com"),
    domain("stackexchange.com"), domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("superuser.com")
{
    #sidebar {
        display:                none !important;
    }
    #mainbar, .mainbar, #questions, .question-summary, #answers, .answer {
        min-width:              728px !important;
        width:                  100% !important;
    }
    .summary {
        min-width:              630px !important;
        width:                  calc(100% - 120px) !important;
    }
    .question > table {
        width:                  100% !important;
    }
    .post-text, .wmd-preview, .post-editor, .wmd-input {
        min-width:              660px !important;
        width:                  100% !important;
    }
    .wmd-button-bar {
        min-width:              634px !important;
        width:                  100% !important;
    }
}
```

---

### Important!

- This has not been extensively tested and only on Firefox, but it
  should work with stylish for Chrome, Opera, etc. too.
- I don't use this style. Support for this low demand functionality will be limited.

Comment: That is a very good start. On the question pages, it does exactly what I want. Other pages are still slightly misformatted. Would you be willing to post it on e.g. GitHub? This would make it easier to point to the places it still lacks and improve upon it.

Comment: i edited the width of the #mainbar to 50%. My requirement is to keep the default content width setting. But when I reduce the size of the window width, it should still to stay the same width.

Comment: I still needed this script, because simply hiding using, #sidebar { display:none !important; } , the content width will be shrinked too small, when the window width is reduced. (Eg. I put my monitor in portrait mode, and maximise the window)

Comment: Stylus extension is now recommended over Stylish (privacy concerns).

Answer (score 3):

I made a userscript that allows the user to toggle the visibility of the sidebar (the userscript's source code is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/double-beep/my-userscripts/blob/master/toggleSidebar.user.js)):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Toggle the right sidebar
// @version      0.5.2
// @author       double-beep
// @contributor  Scratte
// @description  Add the ability to toggle the right sidebar
// @include      /^https://(?:[^/]+\.)?(?:(?:stackoverflow|serverfault|superuser|stackexchange|askubuntu|stackapps)\.com|mathoverflow\.net)/*
// @exclude      https://*.*/review*
// @updateURL    https://github.com/double-beep/my-userscripts/raw/master/toggleSidebar.user.js
// @downloadURL  https://github.com/double-beep/my-userscripts/raw/master/toggleSidebar.user.js
// @license      MIT
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    const buttonWrapper = document.createElement('li');

    const toggleButton = document.createElement('a');
    toggleButton.id = 'hide-sidebar';
    toggleButton.title = 'Toggle visibility of right sidebar';
    toggleButton.innerHTML = '&#10095;';
    toggleButton.classList.add('s-topbar--item');

    buttonWrapper.appendChild(toggleButton);

    document.querySelector('.s-topbar--content').appendChild(buttonWrapper);

    const sidebar = $(document.querySelector('#sidebar, .sidebar'));
    const mainbar = document.querySelector('#mainbar, .mainbar');

    document.querySelector('#hide-sidebar').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
        if (sidebar.is(':visible')) {
            sidebar.hide(200);
            $(mainbar).animate({ width: '100%' }, 200);
            target.innerHTML = '&#10094;';
        } else {
            sidebar.show(200);
            mainbar.style.width = 'calc(-324px + 100%)';
            target.innerHTML = '&#10095;';
        }
    });
})();
```

The button is in the menu bar:

[image]

Comment: interesting. I tried this, it works but i can't click the same button to unhide it. useful if it can hide by default too.

Comment: to run this, need to install tampermonkey, on chrome/firefox.

Comment: Works like a charm in Firefox, but only on the Q&A pages. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

and this too: [StackOverflow CodeBox Options](https://stackapps.com/questions/8013/stackoverflow-codebox-options)

[image: options-menu]

Answer (score 0):

Nice small chrome extension. Adds a toggle button to show/hide.
Minor con though, it shows the sidebar for a millisecond before the javscript kicks in.

[Toggle Stackoverflow sidebar - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-stackoverflow-side/jhgooipphocncabpmflocgdmhojmhibi/related)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find my plugin which does just that for Firefox [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stackoverbloat/).

Comment: But it is exclusively for StackOverflow, and not the Stack Exchange platform, so not really appropriate for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can just block the element with Brave's right click menu, or the uBlock Origin add-on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Apps! Could you please elaborate a bit - for instance, does it work across all sites in the network?