# StackOverflow CodeBox Options

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, firefox, userstyle

This Tampermonkey script adds options to StackOverflow to

1. expand answer box
2. expand code box
3. resize code font size
4. widen the entire page
5. remove sidebar

Source: https://github.com/yodog/userscripts/blob/master/stackoverflow-code-box-options.user.js

Install: https://github.com/yodog/userscripts/raw/master/stackoverflow-code-box-options.user.js

Feedback much appreciated

---

Update: now its not necessary to refresh the page to apply the changes.
Update: added several other sites from the stack exchange network.

[image: so-menu]
[image: so-wide-screen]

Comment: at the time i created the script i didn't know that i could disable the sidebar natively. that's why the option exists.